# Return many object in my json response using resource

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, resources

I'm kinda new to Laravel and I hope someone we'll be able to give me some help.

I apologize for my english

So I'm trying to develop an application with some friends to manage our food by sending alert when the peremption date is near.

I'm developing the API, the actual structure is this way:

A user,

A product,

A basket containing the user_id, the product_id and of course the peremption date.

So now when I make a call to get the User 'stock' on my API I wish I could get something like this:

```
{
  'id' : 1,
  'peremption_date': XX-XX-XX,
  'product' : {
           'id' : 3,
           'name': bblablabala,
           'brand' : blablabala
  },
  'id' : 2,
  'peremption_date': XX-XX-XX,
  'product' : {
           'id' : 4,
           'name': bblablabala,
           'brand' : blablabala
  },
}
```

So I took a look on resources and saw that if I define the right relations, this could do the stuff for my output.

I'll link you my actual class declarations and their resources:

User:

```
//user.php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function baskets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Basket::class);
    }
}
```

Product:

```
//Product.php

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = ['code_barre', 'product_name', 'generic_name', 'brand', 'quantity'];

    public function basket()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Basket::class);
    }
}

//productResource.php
class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'code_barre' => $this->code_barre,
            'product_name' => $this->product_name,
            'generic_name' => $this->generic_name,
            'brand' => $this->brand,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Basket:

```
//Basket.php
class Basket extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'baskets';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'product_id', 'dlc_date'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
    }
}

//BasketResource.php

class BasketResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'dlc_date' => (string) $this->dlc_date,
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at,
            'product' => $this->product
        ];
    }
}
```

So when I try to store a new basket in my store method:

```
//BasketController.php
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->product->storeProduct($request->input('code_barre'));
        $att = DB::table('products')
            ->where('code_barre', '=', $request->input('code_barre'))
            ->first();
        $basket = Basket::create([
            'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
            'product_id' => $att->id,
            'dlc_date' => $request->input('dlc_date')
        ]);
        return new BasketResource($basket);
    }
```

I get the following error [(this one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MYzW.png)

saying than products.id_basket does not exist and its right, it's not supposed to exist. This is Basket who have a product_id. so I know this is coming from the relationship I declared but I can't figure how to do it right.

Can someone come and save me ???

Thanks a lot, I hope you understood me !
Wish you a good day

Comment: Can you please share your database structure for these tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I look at your `Basket` model, it seems you have to change your:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
}
```

to:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Because you have `product_id` in your `baskets` table. To use `hasOne()` relation, you will need to remove `product_id` from `baskets` table and add `basket_id` to `products` table, because `hasOne()` relation is something like `hasMany()`, only calling `->first()` instead of `->get()`

Comment: thanks a lot !!! That worked. It's so abstrait for me at the moment, hopefully you helped me. Thanks again ! have a good day!